# AWS CLI S3 sync error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to sync my static website with S3 bucket using this command:

```
aws s3 sync folder s3://my-bucket --region us-west-2 --delete --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=7200" --exclude "*" --include "*.html"
```

I have about 300 HTML files spread across several subfolders. The command above crashes on the last file with `('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))` error. The process always hangs on the very last file and then returns that error.

I tried changing **max_concurrent_requests** to 1 and **multipart_chunksize** to  2MB with no luck. The process successfully uploads 299 files out of 300 and then get stuck on the last file. Then a `('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))` error reported.
The last file doesn't get uploaded.

I tried search for that error, but found no working solution. I'm on Windows 10 and website folder isn't encrypted.

What can cause that error?

Comment: What is different about the last file? How large is the file? Who is your ISP (home or business class). If you delete (temporarily) the last file does the process succeed or does it now fail on the new last file?

Comment: @JohnHanley Nothing particular. All HTML files are about the same. If I remove the last, it gets stuck on new last file.

Comment: Add the command line option --debug. Then review what is happening near the end. If you try to sync just one file what happens?

Comment: @JohnHanley One file uploads successfully.
When I execute the command with --debug flag in it, it says "Shutdown request received in result processing thread, shutting down result thread.". I didn't press Ctrl+C though.

Comment: Do you have Antivirus installed? If true, temporarily disable it and try again.

Comment: @JohnHanley Only built-in Windows protection. I disabled Runtime Antivirus protection yet the command with --debug flag finishes with the same result.

Comment: Try just using "aws s3 cp --recursive --debug" plus your path params. I am interested in both the error and the lines that indicate what was happening that generated the error. Also, please answer each question. You may think not important but I ask each item for a reason.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm trying to upload from home. I already tried cp command several times and never saw it failing. Unfortunately, I need --delete option not present for the cp command.

Comment: @JohnHanley I re-enabled built-in antivirus but added my project folder as an exclusion for it. Now aws s3 sync completed successfully. Quite weird.
You asked about ISP. Did you mean the ISP may throttle my requests?

Comment: I have seen many issues with home ISPs. Cheap routers that get confused on lots of uploads (reboot the router). Detection of business types of activities (drop your connection). For large uploads (1 GB+) I often see connections dropping. I have one of those types of ISPs at home so I see this often when I am not using a VPN (which indicates that they are looking at my traffic).

Comment: The suggestion to use aws s3 cp is to debug your problem. Not to replace your solution. I had a feeling that it was antivirus as the problem appears to be happening  during data transfers that have already been cached into buffers that aws s3 sync uses but aws s3 cp does not use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bring summary of the discussion from comments here.

The problem can be caused by several reasons, including:

- Home ISP breaking your connections thinking you're doing business activities.
- Antivirus software working on your computer.
- File sizes.

Try this first if `s3 cp` command works but `s3 sync` doesn't. Add project's folder into the exclusions list of your anti-virus software. If you're using anti-virus built into Windows 10, open "Virus & thread protection" settings page. Click on the "Virus & thread protection" header - this will open advanced settings. Under "Exclusions" select "Add or remove exclusions" link. Add your project folder there.

If adding the project folder into anti-virus' exclusions list doesn't help, try to use VPN for file upload. This hides amount of connections you make from your ISP's eyes.

Many thanks to @JohnHanley for suggestions.